# Как проверить строку на наличие ссылки?

Tags: python

Хочу сделать бота для автоматического исключения участника из беседы если в его сообщении присутствует ссылка. Исключение то сделать легко, а вот проверку сообщения на ссылку нет. Может быть есть какая то библиотека или что-то еще?

Comment: `re`...................

Comment: `re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', url)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так вот с помощью модуля `urlextract`:

```
import urlextract

extractor = urlextract.URLExtract()
urls = extractor.find_urls('google.com and stackoverflow.com')
print(urls)
urls = extractor.find_urls('nothing')
print(urls)
```